# Is Glassfish an overkill if using Spring and not using EJB?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, glassfish, facelets

In a nutshell, I am trying to evaluate, in a scenario of a Spring-based web application not using EJB, if Glassfish offers any features that Tomcat does not that would make it worth using.  In other words, if I am using Spring security, transaction management, as well as MVC (would like to use Facelets but then again, Spring Web Flow offers Facelet support), and not really any container management features of Glassfish that can't be found in Tomcat, are there any advantages of using Glassfish over the simpler Tomcat platform and what are they?  Additionally, does it, in any scenario, make any sense to mix Spring MVC and JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/GlassFish_vs_Tomcat) is pretty old, but might help.

Personally, I am a firm believer in not using an app server that has features I will never use, and since I still have a horrible taste in my mouth from past EJB experiences, I don't see myself willingly using them again, so I personally wouldn't consider Glassfish as Tomcat has everything I need.  If all you need is added admin tools, there are plenty of commercial-grade Tomcat offerings out there, like SpringSource's [tcServer](http://www.vmware.com/products/application-platform/vfabric-tcserver/overview.html) (which I have personally used I liked quite a bit) or MuleSoft's [Tcat](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-admin).  ReHat also had some enterprise Tomcat offering at one time, but the product name escapes me at the moment.